# Upload CSV file with 50000 records and insert data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv-import

I need to upload csv and import this data to MySQL table.

```
    public function insertData()
    {
        while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $query = "INSERT into deleted_users (email)
                   values ('" . $column[0] . "');                $query->execute();
                       }
}
```

Comment: Try to update your question and add some information on what you are trying to improve. If you are running into a problem, describe the problem clearly.

Comment: The prepare() should be outside the loop (prepare once, execute multiple...) - and it should use placeholders, as your current code is susceptible fro SQL injections.

Comment: Is the file local or on the MySQL server?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen inside my project directory

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fastest way to bulk load data from PHP into MySQL is to use the `LOAD DATA` tool, something like this:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/yourfile.csv'
    INTO TABLE deleted_users
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (@col1)
    SET email = @col1;";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

This answer loads records with only the `email` field being assigned.  If you want to assign a value for the `id` and `type` columns, then you will need a CSV file containing these values.

Comment: table has id, email, type columns, type is static value and its not come with csv

Comment: im getting file path errors, im taking the file uploaded from front end do I need to store it somewhere, isn't it possible to take tmp file  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] ?

Comment: @trazy97 Try using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` in this case.